# ViewState in a HttpHandler?

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page that I want to convert to an `HttpHandler`, but I'm struggling with `ViewState` that's been used in the code behind of the aspx page. How do you solve this?

Comment: What do you mean "convert to an http handler"? Are you still outputting html?

Comment: @Rob Fonseca-Ensor: I think Lieven means casting

Comment: two options, Lieven, which are you trying to do:
1) you've got a reference to a `Page`, but you want to make this reference more generic, so you've cast it to an `IHttpHandler`. Now you don't have access to the ViewState collection...
2) you've got an `aspx` file that's happy spitting html to the browser. you're trying to convert it to an `ashx`. This is a noble cause, but in your case, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Well, based on all the answers, it's probably better to just leave it as an aspx page. thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your page relies on ViewState it's probably not a good candidate for an HttpHandler. ViewState is used to persist values of controls between postbacks. Handlers should be stateless and not depend on postbacks.

Answer (score 2):

Viewstate is rendered to the client as a hidden form field. You can emulate Viewstate by rendering an `<Input Type="Hidden"` tag to your (now manually generated?) html.

Like Darin says though, it's better to either make your response stateless, or leave it as a Page